# Angular - customize the json filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter

I am trying to customize the json filter to add links in it. I've look at how it is build in the source code and tried to fiddle with it. 
The idea is to add links on the items keys as per below. I know this doesn't work but I have absolutely no clue on how to proceed next.

```
;(function() {
angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('testCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      name: 'bob',
      lastname: 'dylan'
    }
  }])

  .filter('customJson', function () {
    function toJsonReplacer(key, value) {
      if (typeof value === "string")
        return '<a href="http://test.com/' + vaue; '" >' + value + '</a>';

      return value;
    }

    function toJson(obj, pretty) {
      if (typeof obj === 'undefined') { return undefined; }
      return JSON.stringify(obj, toJsonReplacer, pretty ? '  ' : null);
    }
    return function(object) {
      return toJson(object, true);
    };
  });
})();
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Use the [`linky` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky)?